# Exponential Function with large numbers in python

Tags: python, numbers, bignum

I was working with a dataset in python, where i have to convert the data points into exponential form to capture the relationship. Say, the number is 1000, np.exp(1000) gives me inf (due to overflow),whereas mp.exp(1000) gives me the exponential form somewehre in the order  say,1e450. 
I converted this number to int terms, getting a huge number. But i cannot use it in any of my functions, cannot run a regression, nor scale it using standard scaler, because this huge number is supported only as an object type. How do we work with such large numbers
?

Comment: Can you add one or two example what you want to do with those numbers. Often times in such a situation you can do your calculations directly on the exponents (like 1000) avoiding using those large numbers explicitly (e.g. think about taking your equation of interest and applying a logarithm to it and see if you can rearrange it appropriately).

Comment: "np.exp(1000)"

returns inf..

hence i used mpmath, mp.exp(1000)
returns 1.86762808634619e+460

I cannot input this feature into standard scalers or any other process because it doesnt support data types.

Hence i printed it 
print('my_variable')
import mpmath as mp
for i in df_out['my_variable']:
    num=(mp.exp(i))
    
    print(num)

this is stored again as an object in my dataframe, and i am stuck.

Comment: My end goal is to run a regression for this feature.Hence i need it in numerical type. Float doesnt  support.  Whereas int does support. By i cannot convert it from objects dtype now.I tried conversion into logarithmic from, but tehn the relationship isnt captured properly

Comment: There's not really enough information here. I don't understand what you mean by "this huge number is supported only as an object type". python integers can be arbitrary precision, and the python decimal package supports arbitrary sized values as well.